# AWS Serverless Endpoint Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

Hi i'm an AWS newbie over here. So far I've been through many sites and forums to search for the errors that i have been getting but am unable to do so. I'm doing this on AWS Cli.

After running sls deploy, i keep getting this on AWS endpoint

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

After checking cloudwatch logs, this error popped out;

```
Unable to import module 'index': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I have left the link to my zip file here for perusal;
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/files/2087709/annotation.zip

Would appreciate any help that is provided, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no index.js file inside your zip file, either you can rename lambda.js -> index.js or change Handler from Lambda console to lambda.handler as shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Finally managed to solved it. I was spending almost 3 hours trying to solve this issue just now. Thread closed, thanks!